# How to get all log lines between two time ranges?

Tags: php, regex, awk, grep

I have log files that has lines like so :

```
2017/10/18 00:00:00 [WARNING]
2017/10/18 00:10:00 [WARNING]
2017/10/18 00:20:00 [WARNING]
2017/10/18 01:00:00 [WARNING]
2017/10/18 01:10:00 [WARNING]
2017/10/18 01:20:00 [WARNING]
```

For example, i want to get all lines between `2017/10/18 00:15:00` and `2017/10/18 01:15:00` .

I've been trying to use grep and regex for this, but i cant find a solution. i've read several solution ([like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123979/how-to-extract-logs-between-two-time-stamps)) and learned about awk. but it seems like awk need a regex pattern too ?

Comment: Why not convert each line's datetime to a `Datetime` object and then test against the `Datetime` object to see whether or not it fits within the range? No need to use regex for this (other than extracting the datetime) and it's a little more elegant

Comment: What language are you after an answer in? Something on the unix/linux shell or PHP? You have conflicting tags in your question...

Comment: @Matt_S, im using exec() on php script, so both solution are fine i guess.

Comment: @ctwheels: note that you don't need to convert anything here since the date and time are written in a format that follows the "alphabetic" order and where each value is left padded with zeros. (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are correct, alphabetical ordering will work in this case. An overlook on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `awk` like this:

```
awk '$1" "$2>="2017/10/18 00:15:00" && $1" "$2<="2017/10/18 01:15:00"' file
```

You may also use variables for begin and end:

```
#!/bin/bash
BEGIN="2017/10/18 00:15:00"
END="2017/10/18 01:15:00"
awk -v begin="${BEGIN}" \
    -v end="${END}" \
    '$1" "$2>=begin && $1" "$2<=end' file
```